# R predict factor variables

Tags: r, predict

I try to do some prediction in R . I loaded & cleaned the data, fit a model and did a prediction which looks pretty good. My problem now is that my prediction gives me a percentage of probability of the occurence of e certain factor instead of the factor itself:

I have a dataset on how well people perform some exercise. This performance is messured in A-D ( which is a factor-variable in my dataset). When I do the prediction I get this output:
[image]

but I want to have it like that:

**[ B    A    E    A    A    C    D    A    A    A    C ]**

**How would I do that?** This is my code:

```
modFitA1 <- rpart(classe ~ ., data=PML_Train_red, method="class")     
Predictn<-predict(modFitA1, newdata= PML_Test_red)
Predictn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you put `method="class"` in your model statement,  you need to add `type="class"` to your predict statement.

```
Predictn<-predict(modFitA1, newdata= PML_Test_red, type="class")
```